# Extension point to register perspective listener

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have a plug-in that needs to register for the debug events. However, it is quite likely that it will be activated after the debugging session has been started. So what I am looking for is some extension point that would allow me to listen to the perspective changes (i.e. I can register for the debug events when the debug perspective is opened).

The other solution is to use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point, but it is discouraged.

Comment: Where did you see that `org.eclipse.ui.startup` is discouraged?

Comment: Here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_I_activate_my_plug-in_when_the_workbench_starts%3F The problem is, that a user may always disable the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IPartListener` to listen for one of the debug views becomes active. The debug views can be used outside of the debug perspective, the `IPartListener` has the advantage of working in this case as well.

Comment: Hmm, this probably would not work out. My problem is that I have to activate my plug-in when the debug perspective is opened. To listen for the part lifecycle events I need to have my plug-in already activated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, albeight not elegant. You can add a org.eclipse.jdt.debug.breakpointListeners extension to your plugin. Make sure that the filter property of the breakpoint listener is set to "*" so you listen to any break point. I asked eclipse to create the IJavaBreakpointListener implementaiton automatically (after adding the extension) and didn't modify anything.

As soon as a debug session is started, it will cause your plugin to load (i.e. Activator will be started).